# Completely cut of web.config inheritance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, web-config, reverse-proxy

We're looking to relocate an existing site located under support.aaa.com to www.aaa.com/support. However, the existing root level web site is ASP.Net and the support web site is ASP.Net MVC based. The later Web.config has conflicting setting with the root web.config. Sadly these settings cannot be simply overridden using a location tag. Is there any way it could be done?

The only solution I've identified is using a reverse proxy to route the /support traffic to support.aaa.com

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could stop the configuration from cascading down in the parent configuration with the [InheritInChildApplications Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications.aspx) if that's any help to you?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, there's conflicting section in the Sections group and I haven't found a way to cut off inheritance for this.